# Add a simple calendar in my website synchronized with AirBNB *.ics

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm building a website for flat rental. I need to include in it a calendar (small, basic, only month dates busy/free) synchronized with the **AirBNB** one for the same property. AirBNB offers me a link with a ***.ics** file making use of **Ical** protocol (same as Google Calendar AFAIK).

I'd be updating the AirBNB calendar from their site and would like to have the calendar in my website synchronized with it simply showing which dates are free/busy to be rented.

I'm developing the website making use of **PHP** and **jQuery**. I'm thinking of a solution making use of any/both of them but an `<iframe>` solution or similar would do the trick too.

I've googled all over and believe I simply can't understand whether they're solutions to my problem or kind of the opposite (update by importing into AirBNB calendar).

Any idea, suggestion, more than welcome. Thank you in advance,
hip

Comment: Still searching for ANY solution. Last thing I thought of is importing/synchronizing AirBNB calendar into Google Calendar (GC) and inserting (HTML) GC into my website. But still not sure how to do it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would reverse engineer airbnb's rest calls on their mobile/web app and make the same calls to update calendar after you log them in.

Using PHP/jQuery is irrelevant to the matter here.

Comment: I may be totally lost but I'm not asking about mobile nor apps but a plain website. On the other hand I don't understand what you mean by 'reversing engineer airbnb's rest calls'.
Thanx anyway Tommy Chan